# How to use bookmark for complex shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How to bookmark a complex shiny app which having `tabs`, more `SelectInput` widgets, `conditional panel`, `uploaded files`.

Any suggestions will be accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use server-side bookmarking or create a downloadable custom file that will hold the state of the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @zimia. I tried server side bookmarking but it is not working for me. It is not holding user inputs. For the second option downloadable custom file I was getting error in restoring that. Can you help me with the detail explanation on how to create a custom file.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example to demonstrate what you have done so far.

Comment: Please see: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html